# What's the benefit of using a template method in the wikipedia example for Factory Method pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-method

The [Wikipedia article about factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

contains this example:

```cs
/* Almost same as Factory, just an additional exposure to do something with the created method */
public abstract class ProductAbstractFactory
{
    protected abstract IProduct MakeProduct();

    public IProduct GetObject() // Implementation of Factory Method.
    {
        return this.MakeProduct();
    }
}

public class PhoneConcreteFactory : ProductAbstractFactory
{
    protected override IProduct MakeProduct()
    {
        IProduct product = new Phone();
        //Do something with the object after you get the object. 
        product.SetPrice(20.30);
        return product;
    }
}
```

where the template method pattern is used too (`GetObject` calls abstract `MakeProduct`). In this (specific) case, I wouldn't do it that way, because the template method doesn't contain any "surrounding" code and making `GetObject` abstract with overrides in derived classes would be sufficient.

Do I oversee something here?
Or I'm right with the assumption, that this example is not as simple as possible as it could be for the demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

In the Gang of Four book, the Factory Method chapter is incredibly broad and in some cases contradictory. For example, the chapter states multiple times that Factory Method relies on inheritance, yet it also describes language-specific variants that avoid inheritance.

The goal seems to have been to list every possible OO mechanism of creating an object. Based on the sheer number of alternatives mentioned, the chapter can be (and has been) interpreted as saying *any* overridable method which returns a new object instance qualifies as a Factory Method.

I (and others) reject this interpretation simply because it makes the pattern name useless. The majority of all methods in an application could meet that definition, at which point it is more informative to reference factory methods simply as... methods, and coin a more descriptive name for the remaining minority.

It is equally plausible to interpret the chapter as generally describing a specialization of the Template Method Pattern, where language-specific variants deserve unique names and should rightly be called idioms rather than patterns. This interpretation has the advantage of being applicable, because it has a meaning rather than having all meaning.

In the wild, you may see every creational pattern under the sun referred to as a factory. The Template Method interpretation attempts to reclaim the terminology for a practical purpose.